# Use of Camunda 8 Partition

Tags: camunda

In Camunda 8, how can I make use of the partition of Zeebe? https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/zeebe/technical-concepts/partitions/

I have read the Camunda 8 docs, and found that there is a partition feature. But I dont know how to apply it into real application. any other resources (docs) related to partition?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be thinking of a multi-tenancy concept. In Camunda 8 partitions are an initial configuration which is set during system setup. It defines the number of 'shards' used to store data and hence has an impact on scalability (how many vCPUs you can be fully utilized with the setup). In the upcoming release it will be possible to add partitions later on to increase the potential scale of the system.  A Camunda 8 partition is not the same as a partition / tenant in Camunda 7.